# Como mostrar imagenes en forma de catalogo en una pagina web

Tags: python, flask

Estoy dando vueltas hace rato probando distintos metodos como subirlas a la base de datos en formato BLOB(no lo hice por lo ineficiente) tambien con pillow pero ninguno me dio resultados, intente con S3 pero no me queda muy claro como se hace y lo unico que logre hasta ahora es que me muestre los nombres de las imagenes.
Cabe aclarar que estoy haciendo esto con python y flask

```
@bp.route("/catalogo", methods=["GET"])
def catalogo():  
    ubicacion = r"C:\Users\benja\proyectos\PaginaWeb\app\moura"
    contenido = os.listdir(ubicacion)

    imagenes = []
    for fichero in contenido:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(ubicacion, fichero)) and fichero.endswith(".jpg"):
            imagenes.append(fichero)
    return imagenes
```

[image: Imagen]

Otro error que cometo y no  se como cambiarlo es que tomate la ubicacion desde paginaweb o app pero me da error

Comment: Lo que quieres es cargar las imágenes en tu servidor local? Y luego mostrarlas en tu front?

Comment: Claro, pero de manera en que no tenga que colocar 1 url por vez en el html y una vez terminado lo subiria a railway

Comment: Puedes hacer una respuesta de tipo File o puedes solo devolver la ruta y luego usar `url_for` para acceder al archivo. Existen varias formas como ves